# Within a function that uses non-standard evaluation, check if the arguments are missing and whether a column exists

Tags: r, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

I'm attempting to write a function that does two things.

1. It checks whether or not the arguments are supplied. If certain arguments are not supplied by the user it returns a custom error message.
2. Assuming all arguments are supplied, the function then checks if certain columns are in a data.frame or tibble. I want to note that the user is supplying the column names in the function. If the column supplied by the user is not found in the function then it should return a custom error message

I've been able to write functions that solve both of these issues, however I can't seem to get them to work when they are put in a function together.

Here is a function I created that checks if the arguments are missing:

```r
check_missing <- function(df, x, y, z) {
  if (rlang::is_missing(df)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var df} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(x)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var x} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(y)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var y} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(z)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var z} must be supplied")
  }
}
```

I've also been able to create a function that checks if the values supplied by the user are found in the data.frame or tibble they also provide from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987718/within-a-function-that-uses-non-standard-evaluation-check-whether-a-column-exis). Here is the function:

```r
check_column <- function(df, x, y, z) {
  
  var_x <- rlang::enquo(x) %>% rlang::as_label()
  var_y <- rlang::enquo(y) %>% rlang::as_label()
  var_z <- rlang::enquo(z) %>% rlang::as_label()

   if (!var_x %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_x} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   } else if (!var_y %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_y} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   } else if (!var_z %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_z} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   }
}
```

This is how `check_column` would work:

```r
# create the dataframe
df <- tibble(a = 1:4, b = 9:12, c = 5:8)

# here I am supplying an imaginary variable called "banana" not in the df
check_column(df = df, x = a, y = b, z = banana)
```

In this example, you'll get an error message that says "banana not found in object supplied in `df`"

However, when we try to combine these together, it does not work. I get an error saying "Error: object 'banana' not found". Here is the function that I tried to create by combining them:

```r
combined_fun <- function(df, x, y, z) {
  # check if the arguments are missing
  if (rlang::is_missing(df)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var df} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(x)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var x} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(y)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var y} must be supplied")
  } else if (rlang::is_missing(z)) {
    cli::cli_abort("{.var z} must be supplied")
  }

  var_x <- rlang::enquo(x) %>% rlang::as_label()
  var_y <- rlang::enquo(y) %>% rlang::as_label()
  var_z <- rlang::enquo(z) %>% rlang::as_label()

   if (!var_x %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_x} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   } else if (!var_y %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_y} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   } else if (!var_z %in% colnames(df)) {
     cli::cli_abort("{var_z} not found object supplied in {.var df}")
   }
}
```

Comment: works for me if you use `missing` instead of `is_missing`

Comment: @rawr Yep that works! Can't believe I didn't think of trying that. Thanks!

Comment: seems like something buggy is going on. not sure why `check_missing()` and `check_missing(a)` work as expected but `check_missing(a, b)` starts trying to evaluate `b`

Comment: @rawr Yeah I'm still confused as to why `is_missing()` doesn't seem to work. I might submit a bug report to rlang.

Comment: `rlang::is_missing()` is defined as `missing(x) || identical(x, quote(expr = ))` - so it's not a bug and the `identical()` condition will error if an object is not in scope.  Seems like @rawr must have had `a` defined in their global environment.

Comment: @lotus that's not how `missing` works, and it doesnt matter if i have it defined or not, `missing` doesnt scope or evaluate, `rm('a'); f <- function(a) missing(a); f(); a <- 1; f(); f(a); f(1)` i don't think it is a bug but just a why would anyone want this, the benefit of `missing` is that it does not evaluate `x` which is exactly what `identical(x, ...` does

Comment: @rawr - please re-read my comment.  It was about why OP's function which uses `is_missing()` errors and that the only way `check_missing(a)` does not throw an object not found error is if `a` is defined.  I wrote "the `identical()` condition will error if an object is not in scope" so I'm not sure how you interpreted that as `missing()` scopes and evaluates.

Comment: @lotus `Seems like @rawr must have had a defined in their global environment.` pretty definitive

Comment: @rawr - Right, because you wrote "`check_missing(a)` work as expected but `check_missing(a, b)` starts trying to evaluate b" - but it *does not work as expected* as the only way `check_missing(a)` does not throw an object not found error if for `a` to be defined (again, I'm talking about OP's original function).  Anyway, seems we're talking in circles.  Good luck to you.